# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
string checkUser = " select count(*) form Userdata where Username='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "' ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkUser,conn);

if (temp==1)
{
    Response.Write("User Already Exists");
}
conn.Close();
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146232060   Message=Incorrect syntax near 'Userdata'

```
int temp= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Comment: Well, did you read the sql? What words are "near 'Userdata'"? Do you see anything wrong there?

Comment: Change "form" to "from"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a case of not reading the error message and checking what it refers to.

Comment: You should use SQL parameters to prevent SQL Injection : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: sorry for that i had made correction next time i will take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Userdata'

That tells you that the SQL parser gave up at the word `Userdata` because the syntax no longer made sense, which usually means that the actual error is close before that word.

If you look at that part of your query:

```
select count(*) form Userdata
```

The word right before `Userdata` is `form`, but you should recognise that it's not the keyword `from` that you intended to write.

---

Side note (but an important one): The value that you concatentate into the query is not properly escaped, so the code is wide open to SQL injection attacks. You should use a parameter to put the value in the query:

```
string checkUser = "select count(*) from Userdata where Username = @Username";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkUser,conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBoxUN.Text);
```